# TypeScript compiler API - Extract the type of union type tuple

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

If I have an array of type `string[]` and I want to extract the type from the array, I must do:

```
const typeArgs = type.typeArguments;
typeArgs[0]; // string
```

But what if I have a tuple of type `[number, string]` and want to get the type union of `string | number`?

Comment: What do you mean by getting the type union? I assume you mean to get the individual element types of the tuple type?

Comment: With the example below
`const arr: [string, number] = ['a', 1]`
`arr.map (el => el)`
I need to extract the `el` type.

Answer (score 4):

Getting the individual element types of a tuple type is the similar to getting the element of an array type—use the [`typeArguments`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/17c7c261d429cdc0ec3f957eb7f342a852ef5fd2/lib/typescript.d.ts#L5219) property:

```
const [numberType, stringType] = type.typeArguments;
```

> With the example below `const arr: [string, number] = ['a', 1]; arr.map(el => el)` I need to extract the el type.

If you have access to the `el` node then you can get it and ask what it's type is (`TypeChecker#getTypeAtLocation`). If you don't have access then, for what I know, it is not possible to create `Type` objects using the compiler API. Instead, I would suggest to create your own representation of that transformation based on the `typeArguments` property and use that in your code.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm looking for, `numberType` is a `Symbol` of type `number`.
I need a Symbol of type `string | number`. The `string` and `number` types are for only example. A tuple can be of any type
[T, K, E] => T | K | E

Comment: Creating `Type` objects is not possible with the compiler API for what I know... there is the transformation API to transform an AST, but that's different. I would suggest to create your own representation of that transformation and use that in your code instead based on the `typeArguments` property. Side note: the `typeArguments` property holds types so `numberType` is a type and not a symbol.