# How to retrieve the complete set of types in a UnionType from a symbol using the Typescript Compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I've searched high and low, and even cloned the TypeScript github to try to follow the source. I found this other SO question ([TypeScript compiler API - Extract the type of union type tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983080/typescript-compiler-api-extract-the-type-of-union-type-tuple)), which is a little similar to what I'm trying to do but not exactly.

I'm trying to get the type of a symbol, and if it's a UnionType, I need the complete set of types that make up the union.

If I have TS code like this:

```js
function func(x: string | undefined) {
   if (x === undefined) {
     ...
   } 
}
```

As I traverse the AST using the TS Compiler API, and I come to the BinaryExpression `x === undefined`, what I need is to get the type of the symbol `x`, which I foolishly thought would be straight forward.  I expect this to be a UnionType, but:

```js
const s = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(node.left); // node.left is the left side of the exp (the x)
const t = checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(s, s.valueDeclaration);
console.log(t.isUnion());
```

It logs `false`. The checker thinks `string | undefined` is not a UnionType?

If I change the type of `x` in the function declaration to: `x: string | number | undefined`, then I get `true`.  Why is `string | number | undefined` a UnionType, but `string | undefined` is not?

Further, for `string | undefined` if I log `(t as UnionType).flags`, I get `4` (which is `TypeFlags.String`).  For `string | number | undefined`, the `.flags` property returns `1048576` (which is TypeFlags.UnionType). That's technically true, but not especially helpful. There *is* a `TypeFlags.Undefined`. Its value is `32768`, so why doesn't it return `4 | 8 | 32768` (32780)?  Isn't that usually how bit flags work?

It seems like the type checker is insisting that `| undefined` doesn't count to make something a UnionType. And when you *do* have something that it believe qualifies as a UnionType, there appears to be no trivial way to get at it, since the `.flags` property just gives you back `1048576` instead of the bitwise OR of the types.

Is there any way to actually lookup the type of a symbol and, in the event that it is a UnionType, get a list of the complete set of types that make up that union?

I'll note that I have figured out a way to get the string "string | number | undefined", but  getting the string and manually trying to parse it out feels pretty hacky, and it feels like there would be an "officially approved" way to do it using the TS Compiler APIs?  Further, I don't think the string will work for me, b/c if any of the type are union types themselves, I would need to expand those out to get the full union.

If anyone knows how to do this, you'll be my hero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is string | number | undefined a UnionType, but string | undefined is not?

Enable the `strictNullChecks` compiler option and it will work.

When `strictNullChecks` is `false` the compiler won't store if a type is nullable and so `string | undefined` gets changed to `string`.

Also, once you have the type, then the union types will be on the `types` property:

```
if (t.isUnion()) {
  const unionTypeTypes = t.types;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  For all the digging I did, it never occurred to me that the compiler options I send into `createProgram` would be the missing piece of the puzzle!